# Explicit formula for space curves

Tags: differential-geometry

I've been looking a bit into differential geometry and have gotten stuck on a question:

> Given a function $f,$ is there a way to find the explicit space curve which has $f$ as both it's curvature and torsion?

I've been able to find a formula for a plane curve with curvature $k(s),$ but extending to what seems to be the next simplest case (curvature = torsion) has been difficult.
Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: What does explicit formula mean?

Comment: You have specified a differential equation.  Solve it!  To get started, consider the case $\kappa = \text{constant}, \tau = \text{constant}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\kappa = \tau$, let $U = T + B$ and $W = T - B$.  Derivatives in the following are with respect to arclength $s$.  From the Frenet-Serret formulas, $U'= 0$ so $U$ is constant.  WLOG we can take it to be $[0,0,\sqrt{2}]$.  Now we have $W$ and $N$ orthogonal to $U$ with
$U \times W = 2 N$, so $W = [\sqrt{2} \cos(w), \sqrt{2} \sin(w), 0]$ and 
$N = [-\sin(w),\cos(w),0]$.  Then $W' = 2 \kappa N$ says $w' = \kappa$.  So the first thing you need is
an antiderivative of $w$ of $\kappa$.  Then $T = (U+W)/2 = [\sqrt{2} \cos(w)/2, \sqrt{2} \sin(w)/2, \sqrt{2}/2]$, and integrating this (which requires antiderivatives of $\cos(w)$ and $\sin(w)$) will give you your curve.

Answer (score 0):

Using the curvature and torsion, you can determine the *moving trihedral* of the space curve by solving a certain differential equation. If you wish, you can then use this to get a parameterization of the curve. All the necessary information can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet-Serret_formulas), although they refer to the moving trihedral as the *Frenet-Serret frame*.

Comment: Moving *trihedron* perhaps?

Comment: @Jesse: an emphatic *no*. A *trihedron* would be a surface of 3 faces (which is impossible in Euclidean geometry, the same way that a two-sided polygon is not possible in the plane). A *trihedral* (the noun and the adjective forms are spelled the same way) is a figure formed by three non-coplanar lines intersecting at a point. (Yes, an *-al* ending can be a noun; the *transversal* is the noun, while two surfaces can be *transverse* to each other.) See, e.g. James and James, _Mathematical Dictionary_. Admittedly, the word is somewhat out of fashion nowadays.

Comment: @Willie Wong: That's fair, but I'm still used to hearing _trihedron_.  For example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_frame#The_trihedron) or [here](http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/RectifyingPlane.html).

Comment: @Jesse: Well, in terms of the Greek roots, either is fine.  εδρα means "base" or "facet" or "seat" (legal parlance). For me it is a personal preference to reserve *-hedron* for stuff like polyhedra. Cheers.